# GWT Validation-Api GA

Tags: java, gradle, gwt

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:${gwtPluginVersion}"
    classpath "org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:${grettyPluginVersion}"
  }
}

plugins {
//  id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.9.RELEASE"
  id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.13"
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: "org.akhikhl.gretty"

sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
  main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
  test.java.srcDir "src/test/java"
  test.resources.srcDir "src/test/resources"
}

configurations {
  'vaadin-client' {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-vaadin'
  }
}
//configurations {
//  all*.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
//  all*.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
//  all*.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
//  gwtSdk.exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty'
//}

//configurations.gwt {
//  resolutionStrategy {
//    force 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA'
//  }
//}

dependencies {
  compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpClientVersion")
  compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$httpMimeVersion")
  compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:$httpCoreVersion")

  compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:$javaxInjectVersion")
  compile("com.google.guava:guava-gwt:$guavaVersion")
  compile("com.google.gwt.inject:gin:$ginVersion")

  compile("com.google.gwt:gwt-user:$gwtVersion")
  compile("com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:$gwtVersion")
  // Needed for GWT compile and at runtime for RequestBuilder
  // Specify two artifacts as workaround for GRADLE-1934
//  compile('javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA') {
//    artifact {
//      name = 'validation-api'
//      type = 'jar'
//    }
//    artifact {
//      name = 'validation-api'
//      type = 'jar'
//      classifier = 'sources'
//    }
//  }
  compile("com.gwtplatform:gwtp-mvp-client:$gwtpVersion")

  compile("com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material:$gwtMaterialVersion")
  compile("com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-addins:$gwtMaterialVersion")
  compile("com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-themes:$gwtMaterialVersion")
  compile("com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-table:$gwtMaterialTableVersion")

  compile("com.googlecode.gwt-charts:gwt-charts:$gwtChartsVersion")
  compile("com.google.gwt.eventbinder:eventbinder:$eventBinderVersion")
  compile("org.fusesource.restygwt:restygwt:$restyGwtVersion")
  compile("org.realityforge.gwt.websockets:gwt-websockets:$gwtWebsocketsVersion")

//  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")

  testCompile("junit:junit:$junitVersion")

  compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
  apt("org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion")
}

gwt {
  gwtVersion = '2.8.2'
  maxHeapSize = "4G"
  minHeapSize = "2G";

  modules "com.soft.DeviceManager"
  devModules "com.soft.DeviceManager"

  compiler {
    strict = true;
    disableClassMetadata = false;
    disableCastChecking = false;
  }

  superDev {
    launcherDir = new File('build/inplaceWebapp')
  }

  logLevel = "INFO"
}

gretty {
  springBoot = true
  springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
  httpPort = 8081
  fileLogEnabled = false
  scanInterval = 5
  managedClassReload = false
}

// execute with "-x compileGwt -x war"
task gwtSuperDevDir(type: Copy) {
  into 'build/inplaceWebapp'
  with war
}

// copy war file to $rootDir/install folder
def installDir = "$rootDir" + "/install/"
task installWar(type: Copy) {
  delete installDir
  def sourceFolder = "$buildDir" + "/libs"
  from sourceFolder
  into installDir
}
```

I have such error

```
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
Compiling module com.soft.DeviceManager
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.ConstraintViolationImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/ConstraintViolationImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 31: The type ConstraintViolationImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintViolation<T>.getExecutableReturnValue()
         [ERROR] Line 31: The type ConstraintViolationImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintViolation<T>.getExecutableParameters()
         [ERROR] Line 31: The type ConstraintViolationImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintViolation<T>.unwrap(Class<U>)
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.GwtValidatorContext'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/GwtValidatorContext.java'
         [ERROR] Line 29: The type GwtValidatorContext must implement the inherited abstract method ValidatorContext.parameterNameProvider(ParameterNameProvider)
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.PropertyDescriptorImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/PropertyDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 31: The type PropertyDescriptorImpl must implement the inherited abstract method CascadableDescriptor.getGroupConversions()
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getMessageTemplate()
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getValidationAppliesTo()
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/7d49b53caed9bd81d172807c3e096d24f3c57090/validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar!/javax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator.java'
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Method; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 94: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.GwtBeanDescriptorImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/GwtBeanDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 38: The type GwtBeanDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method BeanDescriptor.getConstraintsForConstructor(Class<?>...)
         [ERROR] Line 38: The type GwtBeanDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method BeanDescriptor.getConstrainedConstructors()
         [ERROR] Line 38: The type GwtBeanDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method BeanDescriptor.getConstraintsForMethod(String, Class<?>...)
         [ERROR] Line 38: The type GwtBeanDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method BeanDescriptor.getConstrainedMethods(MethodType, MethodType...)
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getMessageTemplate()
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getValidationAppliesTo()
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/PropertyDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 31: The type PropertyDescriptorImpl must implement the inherited abstract method CascadableDescriptor.getGroupConversions()
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/ConstraintValidatorContextImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 46: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.ConstraintViolationBuilderImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.addPropertyNode(String)
         [ERROR] Line 39: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.unwrap(Class<T>)
         [ERROR] Line 112: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeBuilderDefinedContextImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeBuilderDefinedContext.addPropertyNode(String)
         [ERROR] Line 79: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeBuilderCustomizableContextImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeBuilderCustomizableContext.addBeanNode()
         [ERROR] Line 79: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeBuilderCustomizableContextImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeBuilderCustomizableContext.addPropertyNode(String)
         [ERROR] Line 112: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeBuilderDefinedContextImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeBuilderDefinedContext.addBeanNode()
         [ERROR] Line 46: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.ConstraintViolationBuilderImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.addParameterNode(int)
         [ERROR] Line 46: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.ConstraintViolationBuilderImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.addBeanNode()
         [ERROR] Line 142: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeContextBuilderImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeContextBuilder.addBeanNode()
         [ERROR] Line 142: The type ConstraintValidatorContextImpl<A,T>.NodeContextBuilderImpl must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeContextBuilder.addPropertyNode(String)
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.NodeImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/NodeImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 25: The type NodeImpl must implement the inherited abstract method Path.Node.as(Class<T>)
         [ERROR] Line 25: The type NodeImpl must implement the inherited abstract method Path.Node.getKind()
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.ConstraintDescriptorImpl'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/impl/ConstraintDescriptorImpl.java'
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getMessageTemplate()
         [ERROR] Line 35: The type ConstraintDescriptorImpl<T> must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintDescriptor<T>.getValidationAppliesTo()
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/7d49b53caed9bd81d172807c3e096d24f3c57090/validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar!/javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider.java'
         [ERROR] Line 54: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Method; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 44: No source code is available for type java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtConstraintValidatorFactory'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/lesharb/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/a2b9be2c996a658c4e009ba652a9c6a81c88a797/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtConstraintValidatorFactory.java'
         [ERROR] Line 26: The type GwtConstraintValidatorFactory must implement the inherited abstract method ConstraintValidatorFactory.releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?,?>)
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

How to make Gradle use validation-api 1.0 GA? This dependence pulls Gretty. Completely eliminate Validation-Api 1.1.0 Final. Or you can make GWT use Validation-Api 1.0 GA

In the future I want to connect more Spring Boot will not there any difficulties?

Gwt + Spring Boot + Gradle did not find any examples on the Internet =(

gradle versions

```
ext {
  slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
  logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
  commonsLoggingVersion = "1.2"

  guavaVersion = "23.0"
  junitVersion = "4.12"
  lombokVersion = "1.16.18"
  httpclientVersion = "4.5.3"
  httpmimeVersion = "4.5.3"
  httpcoreVersion = "4.4.8"

  gwtVersion = "2.8.0"
//  gwtMaterialVersion = "2.1-SNAPSHOT"
//  gwtMaterialAddinsVersion = "2.1-SNAPSHOT"
//  gwtMaterialThemesVersion = "2.0"
//  gwtMaterialTableVersion = "2.1-SNAPSHOT"
  gwtMaterialVersion = "2.0"
  gwtMaterialAddinsVersion = "2.0"
  gwtMaterialThemesVersion = "2.0"
  gwtMaterialTableVersion = "1.0-rc4"

  ginVersion = "2.1.2"
  gwtpVersion = "1.6"
  restyGwtVersion = "2.2.2"
  eventBinderVersion = "1.1.0"
  gwtChartsVersion = "0.9.10"
  gwtWebsocketsVersion = "1.0.4"
  gwtCommonsLang3Version = "3.7-0"

  gwtGradlePluginVersion = "0.6"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your *gradle.properties* with the dependency versions nor did you post the output of `gradle dependencies` so hard to say definitely as that dependency can be pulled in from multiple sources.

But one way is forcing it via the resolution strategy like this:

```
project.configurations.all { config ->
  config.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution({ 
      it.substitute(
         it.module('javax.validation:validation-api')
      ).with(
         it.module('javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA')
      )
  } as Action<DependencySubstitutions>)    
}
```

Comment: I add gradle version

Answer (score 0):

same error i was getting so i have added two jars in class path 
which comes in `gwt 2.8.2 zip`

```
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar

gwt-servlet-deps.jar
```

apart from these u need to have all below jars in class path

```
gwt-validation.jar

gwt-user.jar

gwt-servlet.jar

validation-api.jar
```